# How to get two results with one button using CSS & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Ok what I'm trying to accomplish is once someone clicks a button at the top we'll say the "*Pagado*" button I would like this to also display the "*Pendiente*" results as well whereas we'll say they are related and I want them both to be displayed.

**See image below as the example:**
[image: This is what the page would look like and the buttons at the top would allow you to sort/filter the results]

**Below is what the outcome I'm trying to create...** Once the "Pagado" button is pressed only the results with the "Pagado" mention would be displayed on the page.
[image: This is what I would like to function once a button was selected this results would be displayed.]

Here is the code for the example... http://ibootstrap.net/Snippets/IDXdL46

How to show `Pendiente` and `Pagado` at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a combined `data-status` in your html something like:

`<tr data-status="pagado_pendiente">` where the row has both status say `(Pagado)` and `(Pendiente)`

and in your JS instead of matching the exact string look for `contains` something like:

`$('.table tr[data-status*="' + $target + '"]').fadeIn('slow');` instead of `$('.table tr[data-status="' + $target + '"]').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: very simplistic it worked perfectly... thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

add this js instead of old one and it will work smoothly

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

$('.star').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('star-checked');
});

$('.ckbox label').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.btn-filter').on('click', function () {
  var $target = $(this).data('target');
  if ($target === 'pagado') {
      $('.table tr').css('display', 'none');
      $('.table tr[data-status="' + $target + '"], .table tr[data-status="pendiente"]').fadeIn('slow');
  } else if ($target != 'all') {
      $('.table tr').css('display', 'none');
      $('.table tr[data-status="' + $target + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('.table tr').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

});

i've added new if conditional to your code which check if the target is pagado show this tr plus pendiente tr

```
if ($target === 'pagado') {
      $('.table tr').css('display', 'none');
      $('.table tr[data-status="' + $target + '"], .table tr[data-status="pendiente"]').fadeIn('slow');
  }
```

you can change pagado to whatever you want or add more table rows , cheers.